# Please explain how to find the probability that it passes through the mesh

Tags: probability, proof-verification

A sieve is made of a square mesh of wires. Each wire has diameter d, and the holes
in the mesh are squares whose side length is w. A spherical particle of radius r is
dropped on the mesh. What is the probability that it fails to pass through if it is dropped n times? (Calculations such as these are relevant to the theory of sieving for analyzing the size distribution of particulate matter.)

my answer is $\frac{(w-d-2r)^2}{(w-d)^2}$  am i right?help,i dont't  known how to proceed

Comment: I am not familiar with the formulas needed to compute this, as most users probably are not. If you could post your way of solution, then we can check.

Comment: Before we can answer this question mathematically, I think it is important to know what happens if the spherical particle narrowly makes contact with the wire. Does it bounce back from the sieve, or does it slip through?

Comment: Is $w$ the width of the hole, or is it the distance from one wire center to the next? Also, the probability for failing to pass through (once) should be proportional to the area of the non-hole part, not the area of the hole.

Comment: this question comes from the third chapter of "Mathematical .statistics.and data.analysis,.3rd"   joint distributions , exercise. No more detail were given

Comment: my answer based on hypothesis that the object is stay where it lands  passing through meas passing through without toughing the wires.

Answer (score 0):

If $w$ is the width of a mesh hole, then $(\frac{1}{2}d+w+\frac{1}{2}d)=(w+d)$ is the distance from one wire midpoint to the midpoint of the wire on the opposite side of the hole. If $N$ is the number of holes, then the total area of the mesh is

$$A_{total} = N\, (w+d)^2$$

In order to pass through the hole without touching a wire, the center of the spherical particle needs to be positioned within a smaller square that has the side $(w-2r)$. The total area that allows pass-through is therefore

$$A_{pass} = N\, (w-2r)^2$$

For a single drop, the probability of passing through is

$$P_{pass} = \frac{A_{pass}}{A_{total}} = \frac{(w-2r)^2}{(w+d)^2}$$

And the probability of failing is therefore

$$P_{fail} = 1 - P_{pass}$$

Assuming each drop is an independent event, the probability of failing $n$ drops is

$$(P_{fail})^n = (1-P_{pass})^n = \left(1-\dfrac{(w-2r)^2}{(w+d)^2}\right)^n$$

Comment: Thanks for answering this question, that was cool

Comment: bring me new idea,I suspect the right $A_{pass} is N(w-2r)^2$

Comment: @liuzhiwei You are right! My mistake. I was thinking of diameters, just like for the wires. I have now edited my answer to correct this.